# CSS align second text to first text which might be long or short

Tags: html, css, angular

**edit:** https://jsfiddle.net/mLtnofps/

This shows the problem on a 'mobile device' size - text is not aligned for green text because of its left text

Currently this is the css code which responsible for the alignment:

```
  .info-block .desc {
border-top: 1px solid #e4e8ea;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
margin-top: .5rem;
padding-top: .5rem;
text-transform: none; }
.info-block .desc .desc__info {
  color: #90da85; }
```

This is the HTML template: (working with Angular 4)

```
<div class="info-block" *ngIf="chosenGraphPoint">
            <div class="current"><span>{{ chosenGraphPoint['date'] }}&nbsp;·&nbsp;
                <span class="amount">${{ chosenGraphPoint['stockValue'] }}</span></span>
                <span class="percentage profit" 
                [ngStyle]="{ 'color': chosenGraphPoint['dailyYield'][0] === '+' ? 'green' : (chosenGraphPoint['dailyYield'][0] === '-' ? 'red' : '#4d5a64')}">
                    {{ chosenGraphPoint['dailyYield'] }}</span></div>
            <div class="desc" *ngFor="let outright of changeReason">
                {{ outright['phrase'] }}
                <div class="desc__info" [ngStyle]="{ 'color': outright['color'] }">{{ decideImpact(outright['impact']) }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="news" *ngFor="let tNews of todayNews">
                <div class="news__item" [routerLink]="['/news', tNews.id]" [queryParams]="{date: todayDate, stockId: stock.id}"
                 style="cursor: pointer">NEWS · {{ tNews.source }} · {{ tNews.title }}</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

The relevant part is:

```
    <div class="desc" *ngFor="let outright of changeReason">
                {{ outright['phrase'] }}
                <div class="desc__info" [ngStyle]="{ 'color': outright['color'] }">{{ decideImpact(outright['impact']) }}</div>
    </div>
```

The output is fine but not very aligned:

[image]

The part where **Large Decrease** is fine (expected behavior for the words to split). However, **Medium Decrease** is not on the same pixel with **Large Decrease**

Now, I know this code is not perfect (CSS CODE), but what did I do wrong? is it the:

> {{ outright['phrase'] }}

that isn't handled correctly?

Comment: here you would need either display:grid or display:table/table-cell to draw cols and rows inbricated with each others. flex only draws col by col or row by row . Do you have any plain html instead html+php to share and show your issue ?

Comment: @G-Cyr Yes I have just edited with a proper jsfiddle which present the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the table-layout display instead the flexbox model:

```css
.info-block {
  color: #4d5a64;
  min-width: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  display:table;/* update */
  table-layout:fixed;/* update */
  border-spacing:0 0.25rem;
}
.info-block .desc {
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e8ea;   
  display: table-row; /* update */
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: none;
  box-shadow:0 -1px 0  #e4e8ea;  /*instead border where border-spacing or collapse not reset to 0 */
}
.info-block .desc .desc__info {
  color: #90da85;
  display:table-cell;/* update */
   white-space:nowrap;/* if to keep on a single line */
}


.info-block span:last-of-type {
  width:0;
  text-align:right;
  display:table-cell;
}
.info-block  .current {
  display:table-row;
  box-shadow:0 -1px 0  #e4e8ea;
}
.info-block  .news {
  display:table-row;
  box-shadow:0 -1px 0  #e4e8ea;
}


 .info-block .percentage {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.info-block.bordered {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e8ea;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.info-block .percentage.profit {
  color: #15c235;
}

.info-block .percentage.loss {
  color: #fc3021;
}

.info-block .news {
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e8ea;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  padding-top: .5rem;
}

.info-block .news .news__item {
  color: #4cabd7;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-block">
  <div class="current">
    <span>18.Nov 2017&nbsp;·&nbsp;<span class="amount">$254</span>
    </span>
    <span class="percentage profit">+3.5%</span></div>
  <div class="desc">Won EPL Game against REEDING
    <div class="desc__info">Dramatic Increase</div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">Won EPL Game against REEDING
    <div class="desc__info">Dramatic Increase</div>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">Expecteations for the EFL cup got better
    <div class="desc__info">Dramatic Increase</div>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <div class="news__item">NEWS · CNN · Lorem Ipsum News Item</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work. However, it breaks a bit of my code. I did not think it will act like it. Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x74wgroc/

Comment: You need to reset display on .news and current too. and tune a couple of rules. margin can be reproduced via border-spacing inside a displayed table-layout. https://jsfiddle.net/x74wgroc/1/ (snippet also updted) border-spacing + padding example https://jsfiddle.net/x74wgroc/2/